# using data generator inside dash/plotly callbacks

Tags: callback, generator, intervals, yield, plotly-dash

I am trying to employ a data generator inside a callback of a dash app. The idea is to plot some values which are being updated within a data generator function. The generator is created using yield and my question is that how can I employ the generator in an correct way in dash applications. Here are some information that might be helpful for problem clarification:

```
# generator
def generator():
    while True
        # do some calculations
        yield output
```

and some information about the app itself:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1(children='Trial'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph_1', style={'float': 'left','margin': 'auto'}),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph_2', style={'float': 'left','margin': 'auto'}),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph_3', style={'float': 'left','margin': 'auto'}),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='graph-update',
            interval=2*1000),
    ]
)

#############
## callback
#############
@app.callback([Output('live-graph_1', 'figure'),
               Output('live-graph_2', 'figure'),
               Output('live-graph_3', 'figure')],
              [Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')])
def update_data(input_data):
   
   # step 1
   ###########################################
   # use data generator to produce new data;
   # which is not a simple loading or importing
   # function.
   ###########################################
   new_data = next(generator)

   # step 2
   # create three figures using new_data

   # step 3
   return fig1, fig2, fig3
```

It should be reminded the generator is already tested and next(generator) is producing correct values for each call; also, the dash app is working perfect without generator, but the combination results in errors like:

```
Callback error updating live-graph_1.figure, live-graph_2.figure, live-graph_3.figure
StopIteration
new_data = next(generator)
```

I would really appreciate any help on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

The `StopIteration` exception indicates that [that there are no further items produced by the iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html). Based on the error you see, it thus seems like the error is not related to the Dash application but rather the implementation of your iterator (it runs out of data).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, indeed, the `new_data = next(generator)` works well out of dash and produces new data set for each `next`; however, inside the dash it raises such an error. I think the problem goes back to the employment of `next` inside the callback.

Comment: I haven't heard about any problems with applying next in a callback context before. However, as you are creating the generator as a global variable (which is not recommended, see e.g. https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks), you might see strange behavior - in particular if you have multiple clients, as they will all share the same generator object.

Comment: That's true as generator is not static. Then, would it be possible to employ a dash app inside a generator itself?

Comment: I don’t think that would be possible. Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve with the generator?

Comment: in fact, the generator is a neural network model that makes some predictions for some images. To put it simply, an image is read (like a video frame), then a neural network is called to make predictions, and then the image and its predictions are being used in dash app to provide a kind of real time visualization. Each   `next(generator)` gives a data structure (like data structure in c) in which predictions for a new image is provided.  Dash is being used to steam frames of videos and their predictions.

Comment: Ah, i see. What you could do is to implement a 'get_latest' function, which just returns the latest image. Alternatively, if you need the images to be rendered in order, you could keep the index of the current image in a 'Store' component and always ask for the next image in the series.